# Is there any way to export data from pardot using python?

Tags: python, automation, salesforce, pardot

Currently its a manual process as mentioned below in the link:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pardot_export_prospects.htm&type=5

Can we use python to fetch data instead of doing manual work? Please share an example of the code

Comment: For the issue 46 discussion of PyPardot4 (I suggested a solution in the thread), I forked it to create PyPardotSF that includes the flow to obtain the refresh token. PyPardotSF also supports Ver 3 API: https://github.com/anelendata/PyPardotSF
(not enough reputation on stackoverflow to comment in the previous thread :p )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Official Pardot API Documentation](https://developer.pardot.com/) and [PyPardot](https://github.com/mneedham91/PyPardot4) - Python API wrapper for Pardot.

See [querying objects](https://github.com/mneedham91/PyPardot4#querying-objects) for code example and [querying prospects](https://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-4/prospects/#querying-prospects) section of API docs for supported operations.

Comment: lily, thanks for sharing the details. I was trying to authenticate my login using the code below.
But I can't login directly through Pardot account as we are using salesforce authentication. Do you know any workaround to login using salesforce to Pardot.
below is the python code I was using:-

from pypardot.client import PardotAPI

p = PardotAPI(
  email='email@email.com',
  password='password',
  user_key='userkey'
)
                
p.authenticate()

This results in "False" for authentication when executed.
Thanks and I really appreciate your response

Comment: Looks like this option will stop working soon. For more details and possible workaround see these links: https://developer.pardot.com/kb/authentication/, https://github.com/mneedham91/PyPardot4/issues/46, https://github.com/anelendata/PyPardot4/commit/bef7422f5dfbfc1ca30b73cc22bd9a89352d1ed8

Answer (score 0):

Review the developer docs shared above and this doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_oauth_and_connected_apps.htm , setup the connected app. Then retrieve the token using the keys and business unit
then use the token to grab what you are looking for using the pardot api

```
response = requests.post(auth_url, data = {
                'client_id':client_id,
                'client_secret':client_secret,
                'grant_type':'password',
                'username':sfdc_user,
                'password':sfdc_pass
                })
print (response)
# Retrieve token
json_res = response.json()
access_token = json_res['access_token']
#print(access_token)
auth = {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + access_token,'Pardot-Business-Unit-Id':sfdc_buid}


response = requests.post(listmember_uri, headers=auth,data ={})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do so but found out that as of February 1, 2021, Pardot will no longer accept userkey, password, and username combinations for Pardot API authentication.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32454200)